# Get rows from a MySQL database where the number of foreign keys are variable.

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

A subset of my database contains 3 tables

> users
>
> user_details
>
> tasks

The main column of the user table is:

> id {PK}

The user details table contains information about the users (only some users have these details, students). Thus the main columns of the users details table are:

> user_id{PK,FK} | supervisor_id {FK}

The `supervisor_id` is an id in the users table. Each student has one supervisor.

Lastly, there is the tasks table where only students create tasks and the main columns of the tasks table are:

> task_id{PK}  |    user_id{FK}

The problem I am having is getting a proper query for, if a supervisor wants to see all his students tasks. I know you can query all the students in the `user_details` table who have the supervisor's id. Then create another query where you select all the tasks whose `user_id` matches that of the first query performed.

This does not seem like a very efficient was to go about achieving this result. Are there better alternatives?

Comment: How? How do you have a database and not know about JOINs? I'm genuinely puzzled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is a [join](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html). Instead of writing two separate queries to get the information, a join will allow you to connect the tables that you have in one query and get the information you need much faster.

```
Select *
From user_details ud
  join tasks t
  on ud.user_id = t.user_id
Where ud.supervisor_id = ?
```

The join essentially allows you to create one big table out of all of the columns of the tables you are using. The `on` keyword tells sql which values go together, so that you know all of the tasks belong to the student whose id matches the id that the supervisor has. Then, you can select whatever columns you like out of either table (as well as a lot of other fancy things).

Answer (score 1):

```
select ud.supervisor_id, ud.user_id, t.task_id
from user_details ud, users u
where ud.user_id = t.user_id
```